# Appending text to an existing file from inside a parallel loop

Tags: r, doparallel

I'm currently processing some data in parallel as part of a larger loop that essentially looks something like this:

```
for (i in files) {
  doFunction 
  foreach (j = 1:100) %dopar% {
    parallelRegFun}
}
```

The `doFunction` extracts average data for each year, while the `parallelRegFun` regresses the data with maximally overlapping windows (not always 1:100, sometimes it can be 1:1000+, which is why I'm doing it in parallel).

Part of the `parallelRegFun` involves writing data to CSV

```
write_csv(parallelResults,
          path = "./outputFile.csv",
          append = TRUE, col_names = FALSE)
```

The issues is that quite often when writing to the output file, the data is appended to an existing row, or a blank row is written. For example the output might look like this:

```
+-----+-------+------+---+-------+------+
| Uid | X     | Y    |   |       |      |
+-----+-------+------+---+-------+------+
| 1   | 0.79  | 2.37 |   |       |      |
+-----+-------+------+---+-------+------+
| 2   | -1.88 | 3.53 | 3 | -0.54 | 3.32 |
+-----+-------+------+---+-------+------+
|     |       |      |   |       |      |
+-----+-------+------+---+-------+------+
| 5   | -0.18 | 1.45 |   |       |      |
+-----+-------+------+---+-------+------+
```

This requires extensive clean-up afterwards, but when some of the output files are 100+MB it's a lot of data to have to inspect manually and clean. It also appears that if a blank row is written, the output for that row is completely missing from the output - i.e. it's not in the data that gets appended to an existing row.

Is there anyway to get the `doParallel` workers to check if a file is being accessed and if it is, to wait until it's not before appending the output?
I thought something like `Sys.sleep()` before the `write_csv` command would work,as it would force each worker to wait a different amount of time before writing, but this doesn't appear to work in the testing I've done.

Comment: Any reason you don't write to separate output files with incrementing file names then concatenate?

Comment: @CPak, it is an option, but for example the last dataset I processed ended up writing 395,106 lines to the CSV, and there are about 500 lines missing/appened to the existing rows. It's just a lot of files to write and then append. If it's not possible to fix, this might end up being what I do.

Comment: You might want to test specifying `.inorder` argument with `foreach` but I haven't really tested how well it works for I/O operations.